# One to Many Mapping Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I'm trying to persist 6 comments with a foreign key of post id in the Comment table in the database, but the last 3 comments override the first 3 comments with a newly added foreign key.

Test class:

```
Comments comments = new Comments("1st Comment", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
Comments comments2 = new Comments("2st Comment", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
Comments comments3 = new Comments("3st Comment", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

ArrayList<Comments> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(comments);
arrayList.add(comments2);
arrayList.add(comments3);

// Insert Without Comment
Post post1 = new Post("1st Post", "1st Post Description", new ArrayList<Comments>(), new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
postReposetory.save(post1);

// Insert With Comment
Post post2 = new Post("2st Post", "2st Post Description", arrayList, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
postReposetory.save(post2);

// Update (Insert Comment)
post1.setComments(arrayList);
post1.setUpdatedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
postReposetory.save(post1);
```

Comment: Did my answer help you? or do you want me to add something to my answer? otherwise, feel free to accept my answer if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you put the same objects of comments and then hibernate consider that you want to change the connections of the comments from `post2` to `post1`.

Therefore you have to construct again the three comments.

```java
    Comments comments = new Comments("1st Comment", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    Comments comments2 = new Comments("2st Comment", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    Comments comments3 = new Comments("3st Comment", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    ArrayList<Comments> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.add(comments);
    arrayList.add(comments2);
    arrayList.add(comments3);

    // Insert With Comment
    Post post1 = new Post("1st Post", "1st Post Description", new ArrayList<Comments>(), new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    postReposetory.save(post1);
    
    // Insert Without Comment
    Post post2 = new Post("2st Post", "2st Post Description", arrayList, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    postReposetory.save(post2);

    // Update (Insert Comment)
    comments = new Comments("1st Comment", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    comments2 = new Comments("2st Comment", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    comments3 = new Comments("3st Comment", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    post1.setComments(List.of(comments, comments2, comments3));
    post1.setUpdatedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    postReposetory.save(post1);
```

In this way, other three objects are created for comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a total of 3 comments instances (so 3 records in the database table), not 3 instances per post.

When you update post1 comments you are giving post2 comments as argument, so the foreign key from comments to post2 will change to post1.

**If you want to have 3 comments per post you need 6 comments instances total (2 posts * 3 comments)**.